# Running a Ruby script via the web

Tags: ruby

I have a small Ruby script that I want to run by visiting a page in a browser. This might seem like a dumb question but what's the easiest way to accomplish this? I haven't found very good documentation on how to get Ruby working with Apache so I'm open to any suggestions at this point.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: server-side applications don't run in the browser, they run on the server. The only programming language that runs in the browser is javascript (and vbscript, I suppose).

Comment: [mod_ruby](https://github.com/shugo/mod_ruby) embeds ruby in the apache web server.

Comment: @sepp2k: I've edited my language. @The MYYN: Have you gotten that to actually work yourself? I haven't had success with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). As shown on that page, it's very lightweight, and Apache is not even necessary. As you get to needing more performance you might use Nginx or Apache as a reverse proxy (serving your static files quickly) and something like [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) to make your application run faster.

But for now, just start using Sinatra. As shown on the home page, you can get started in just a few lines.